# How do I call a method in java from main?

Tags: java, methods, call, program-entry-point, calling-convention

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Test extends ArrayList
{

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().add();
        new Test().contains();
    }



    public boolean add(){
        list.add("cat");
        System.out.println(list);
        return true;
    }

    public void contains(){
        if (list.contains("cat")){
            System.out.println("list contains cat");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("list doesn't contain cat");
        }

    }

}
```

Why isn't the result [cat] list contains cat?
It keeps giving me [cat] list doesn't contain cat.
The first method is working correctly, but why isn't the second one?
Thanks... I'm really new to this.

Comment: What is the purpose to inherit `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're calling both the methods with different instances.

```
new Test().add(); // Creates 1 instance
new Test().contains(); // creates another instance
```

You need to use the same instance to call both the methods.

```
Test t = new Test();
t.add();
t.contains();
```

Every new `Test` object created with by the `new Test()` has its own copy of `list`. That's why when you call `contains()` with the other instance, its still empty as the `list` of the first instance was only added with the string "cat".

Answer (score 1):

because the arraylist is not static, so you are creating two instances of App where each one has its own list variable.

set the variable static and it will work.

```
static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But it is better to use the same instance to call two times.

```
Test test = new Test();
test.add();
test.contains();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `new Test()` twice.  You are creating two instances.  You're adding to the first, and checking for `contains` on the second (newly-created) one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of Test. Then you create two separate instances of "list". First with the String "cat" and the second one empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to extend ArrayList? May be you can try like this...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("cat");
        System.out.println(list);

        if (list.contains("cat")) {
            System.out.println("list contains cat");
        } else {
            System.out.println("list doesn't contain cat");
        }     

    }  
}
```